# how i can use graphql in magento 2.3 and i can setup to magento 2.3?

Tags: magento2.3, pwa, graphql

> i want to know how i can use
>
> Graphql in magento 2.3
>
> is there any good resource's to understand that.
>
> how i can set up to my magento 2.3 project
>
> another question is Vue storefront is PWA ?

Answer (score 0):

You can Check this blog for Graphql:

https://amasty.com/blog/magento-2-api-updates-graphql/
https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/graphql/

For Vue storefront:

https://aureatelabs.com/pwa/magento-pwa-studio-vs-vue-storefront-a-comparison/